# Struts 2 File upload works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE

Tags: struts2

I am having issue with struts 2 file upload for excel file in Internet explorer. It works fine in Chrome and firefox, but I am not sure what I am missing for IE.

Here is the struts config I have:

```
<action name="uploadAction" method="submitServiceProfile" class="serviceProfileAction">
             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
             <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/> -->
             <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                 <param name="allowedTypes">application/ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</param>
                 <!-- <param name="maximumSize">20480</param> -->
             </interceptor-ref>
             <interceptor-ref name="params">
                 <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
             </interceptor-ref>
             <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                 <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
             </interceptor-ref>
             <interceptor-ref name="store">
                 <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="someStack"/>

            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">managerPage</result>
             <result name="error" type="redirectAction">managerPage</result>
             <result name="input" type="tiles">homepage</result>

         </action>
```

Comment: if its working in Chrome and Firefox , your code should be fine . whats the js error you are getting ? Do you have IE9 ? Can you trace the n/w request ?

Comment: I am using IE9.. I put debug pointer in the action class and saw file is null there.

Comment: You need to go in IE9 Developer mode (F9) and check whats happenning with HTTP request

Comment: Not sure if I used the Developers tool correctly, but I don't see anything there. However, in fiddle I get the following message- The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent

Comment: I would like to edit my first answer. I put the debug pointer in first line of action method, but request never gets there. However, I had another debug pointer at set method for fileupload and I confirmed the uploaded file was set in the action class.

Comment: Please check the Developer mode as shown here : http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-faster-with-f12-developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-9/#one .. you should be able to trace the HTTP request when you click on the button for upload

Comment: There is an error on js but not sure where that js coming from, its not anywhere in the project.

Comment: Go the console and find the js ..

Comment: I wonder if IE is screwing with the allowedTypes value and it's not returning one of the allowed values? What happens if you remove the allowedTypes parameter and, in essence, accept anything?

Comment: Although I didn't have the particular javascript in my project, I am not sure where that came from. After full server/pc restart, that error go away in IE too. Thanks for you help user1428716

Comment: Again, thought js was messing it up, but this issue again reappeared. So, I removed allowedTypes interceptor-ref, and guess what? It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user497087 (Thank you!), I completely removed allowedTypes, plus the interceptor-ref "fileupload". Now, the request gets to the action without a problem at any given browser.